# Laravel or PHP how to acces to XML file and read value and properties

Tags: php, xml, laravel, laravel-8, php-8

I have this XML file with this structure and I want to read it from Laravel, for this I use SimpleXMLElement.

I can access the "id" and "colour" attributes but I don't know how to access the value in this case the example would be "porsche or ferrari"

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cars>
    <car id="0001" colour="blue">porsche</car>
    <car id="0002" colour="red">ferrari</car>
</cars>
```

**PHP Code**

```
$xmlString = file_get_contents($filename);

$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {
    dd($child);
}
```

**Output Result**

```
SimpleXMLElement {#562
  +"@attributes": array:2 [
    "id" => "0001"
    "colour" => "blue"
  ]
  +"0": "porsche"
}
```

I can access to ID or colour with $child['id'] or $child['colour'], but I don't know how to access the value of ferrari or porsche

Comment: `dd((string)$child);`

Comment: Your `dd()` output shows it right there - `$child[0]`.  https://3v4l.org/l1QQT#v8.0.21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access properties and attributes like so:

```php
$xmlString = file_get_contents($filename);

$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

foreach ($xml->children() as $car) {
    echo $car; // porsche
    echo $car['id']; // 0001
    echo $car['colour']; // blue

    $carName = (string) $car;
    $carId = $car['id'];
    $carColour = $car['colour'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the truth is that I did tests and tests but I did not see it.
very thankful